# Where should I add the unique identifier cookie code?

Tags: 6, cookies

I want to add a unique identifier in a cookie when the user (anonymous or logged) visits the website. Where should I call this code. I tried calling the code in hook_init but that doesn't work on cached pages. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`hook_boot()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_boot/6) would be the best place for your code:

> This hook is run at the beginning of the page request. It is typically used to set up global parameters which are needed later in the request.
>
> **Only use this hook if your code must run even for cached page views**.This hook is called before modules or most include files are loaded into memory. It happens while Drupal is still in bootstrap mode.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I've tried hook_boot() too. It seems to be I need to change the value bootstrap=1 in the {system} table according to this comment to make it work. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_boot/6#comment-14584 Would there be any other way around this?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, but you could make sure it happens when your module is enabled using a `hook_enable()` function: `function MYMODULE_enable() { db_query("UPDATE system SET boostrap = 1 WHERE name = 'MYMODULE'"); }`, and maybe do the opposite in `hook_disable()`. That way at least you're not manually editing the db

Comment: Thanks Clive, hook_boot() along with hook_enable() , hook
_disable() did the trick. Thanks for your help!